# Change logo on scroll

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have this website: https://lapassion.000webhostapp.com/

My question is about the logo, it is white and when I scroll down a white bar appears, making the logo "disappear".

I have this code on index.html

```html
<div class="navbar-header">
    <a href="index.html"><img src="images/logo.png"></a>
</div>
```

And the css

```css
.navbar img {
  margin-top: 15px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

And I need to change that `img` to another one that I already have in black.

What do I need to do?

Comment: how is the white bar tiggering?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using this CSS you can handle it

```
.navbar.navbar-default.navbar-fixed-top.affix .navbar-header img {
    background-color: black;
}
```

Instead of background , use the code to change the image src - if you wish to change the logo.

This CSS is set during sticky header / scrolling the class .affix-fixed changes to .affix. So you can target your CSS style their, no need of JS changes.

```
.navbar.navbar-default.navbar-fixed-top.affix .navbar-header img {
     content: url(https://www.google.com/logos/doodles/2019/joseph-plateaus-218th-birthday-5462347081580544-s.png);
}
```

Comment: Tried it and it works like you said. But what is the code to change the image src? I tried this but is not working...

    .navbar.navbar-default.navbar-fixed-top.affix .navbar-header img {
    /*background-color: black;*/
 background-image: url(images/logop.png);
}

Comment: Try this will resolve your problem                                                                    .navbar.navbar-default.navbar-fixed-top.affix .navbar-header img {
     content: url(https://www.google.com/logos/doodles/2019/joseph-plateaus-218th-birthday-5462347081580544-s.png);
}

Comment: It did really work with the google image. But when I change the url to a local img (images/logop.png) it doesn't change. Does this only work with images uploaded in the web?

Comment: Worked like a charm! I did put the link of the image on the url content and it worked! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Not a very efficient way, but one of the ways could be this :

```
<html>
<body onscroll="changeHeaderImage()">
<!--     body text -->
</body>
    <script>
    count = 0
    function changeHeaderImage() {
        //check so that it does not change every time you scroll,
        //you can change this condition as per your requirement.
        if(count == 0)
            document.getElementById("imageelement").src = "image.jpeg";

        count = 1

    }
    </script>
</html>
```

or other way would be to add/remove class on scrolling, and class is attached to different image sources.

- You can also make use of `IntersectionObserver API` which is better because you can skip `onscroll` event call which happens at each scroll.